# Outwriting file incorrectly

Tags: python

I have a tab separated file that looks something like this:

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon2  more_info
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C       903delC
chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT     241_243delTTC
chr22   43089657    43089657    -   NM_017436   G       301delG
chr12   53701873    53701875    -   NM_015665   TTC A   1292_1294delTTCinsA
```

and I've written a script to count the number of characters in the mut_codon2 column and out-write the information to a file.

Here's my script:

```
import csv
OutputFileName = "indels_mut_count2.txt"
OutputFile = open(OutputFileName, 'w')

with open("indels_mut_removed.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split('\t')
        chrom = columns[0]
        start = columns[1]
        stop = columns[2]
        strand = columns[3]
        isoform = columns[4]
        codon1 = columns[5]
        codon2 = columns[6]
        info = columns[7]
        length = len(codon1)
        length2 = len(codon2)
        OutputFile.write(''+chrom+'\t'+str(start)+'\t'+str(stop)+'\t'+strand+'\t'+isoform+'\t'+codon1+'\t'+codon2+'\t'+str(length)+'\t'+str(length2)+'\t'+info+'\n')
```

I'm almost positive my problem has something to do with the `OutputFile.write()` because the outputted file has added empty lines after each line I want to output. Here's an example:

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon2  8   10  more_info

chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C       1   1   903delC

chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT     3   1   241_243delTTC

chr22   43089657    43089657    -   NM_017436   G       1   1   301delG
```

However, I'm also getting an error that reads:

`info = columns[7]
IndexError: list index out of range`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use csv reader and csv writer

Comment: Note taken. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv` (as suggested by Arkanosis) is a good option; otherwise:

```
with open("indels_mut_removed.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # removes trainling '\n'
        columns = line.split('\t')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Maybe I should switch to csv.CSVReader. I didn't realize I needed to strip the trailing '\n'

Comment: and for the error: are you sure everything is tab-delimited? or are some fields delimited with spaces (`str.split('\t')` would then not produce an extra entry in the list). in that case `str.split()` (without arguments) should work.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use a `csv.csvreader` instead of splitting the lines manually. Splitting does not handle escaping and a few other things, so the `csv.csvreader` is much safer.

For information, you're experiencing this issue because you dont strip the `\n` at the end of each line — using `rstrip()`, for example. Which you write then to the output, with an added (second) `\n` that you put yourself when you call `write()`.

But again, use `csv.csvreader` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To use csv, you might do something similar to this:

```
import csv

with open(fn) as fin, open(fo, 'w') as fout:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    writer=csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    headers_in=next(reader)
    headers_out=headers_in[:-1]+['len codon 1', 'len codon 2']+headers_in[-1:]
    writer.writerow(headers_out)
    for row_in in reader:
        row_out=row_in[:-1]+map(len, [row_in[5], row_in[6]])+row_in[-1:]
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

Given this input:

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon2  more_info
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C   903delC
chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT 241_243delTTC
chr22   43089657    43089657    -   NM_017436   G   301delG
chr12   53701873    53701875    -   NM_015665   TTC A   1292_1294delTTCinsA
```

Produces this output:

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon2  len codon 1 len codon 2 more_info
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C   1   7   903delC
chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT 3   13  241_243delTTC
chr22   43089657    43089657    -   NM_017436   G   1   7   301delG
chr12   53701873    53701875    -   NM_015665   TTC A   5   19  1292_1294delTTCinsA
```